# ::after won't stack below element

Tags: html, css, z-index

[image]I need the grey vertical line to be underneath "latest work" work. When I set the z-index to negative though it disappears, I assume under the body? Hoping this is a simple solution. I attached an image of my mockup to show what it should look like. I have a div with a background of #212121 so the copy "latest work" has padding above and below and makes it look like the line goes underneath.

```css
body {
 font-size: 16px;
 background: #f9f9f9;
}
.container {
 max-width: 1600px;
}

#dt-lpStatic {
 height:60px;
 width: 100%;
 padding:6px 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.875em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#dt-lpStatic ul {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 3px;
}
#dt-lpStatic ul li {
 display: inline;
 color:#545454;
 margin-left:40px;
}
#dt-lpStatic ul li:nth-child(1) {
 margin-left:0;
}
.subscribe-btn-muted {
 padding:12px 50px;
 border:2px solid #555;
 border-radius: 13%/50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 13%/50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 13%/50%;
 float:right;
 color:#555;
}
#hero {
 width:100%;
 background: #212121;
 height:100vh;
}
#hero-content {
 margin:30vh auto;
 text-align: center;
}
#hero .secTitle-bg-dark {
 width:200px;
 padding: 15px 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin:30vh auto;
 background: #212121;
}
.secTitle-bg-dark:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 65vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #313131;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <section id="hero">
  <header id="dt-lpStatic">
   <div class="container">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="imgs/logo-muted.png" alt="RH logo"></li>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>Blog</li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Get In Touch</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="subscribe-btn-muted">Subscribe</div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div id="hero-content">
   <img src="imgs/logo-full-big.png" alt="RH Visual Design logo">
   <div class="secTitle-bg-dark">latest work</div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a really great candidate for flexbox. You can simplify the code a lot just by doing this:

Edit: Just a friendly tip: Psuedo-elements should be prefixed with `::`, like `::before` and `::after`. Psuedo-selectors only have one colon, like `a:hover` and `input:focus`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.latest-work {
  color: #999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.latest-work span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.latest-work::before,
.latest-work::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="latest-work">
    <span>latest work</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've never used flexbox, but what makes this a good candidate? I thought it was used for grids? Apologies, I am still a nube. Thanks though @ratherblue !

Comment: Okay, I got that too work when I do the code separately, but when I try and make it work with my code it disappears again... I guess I need to look into what I'm doing that is messing that up. But big thanks!!! I see flexbox does A LOT more than what I thought...    \_[-_-]_/

Comment: It's a great candidate because you want the vertical lines to be perfectly centered with the text of "latest work". Because `::before` and `::after` are psuedo-elements, you can manipulate them like a normal element and they fall under flexbox rules.

In the code I entered above, the elements are stacked vertically because I did `flex-direction: column`.

Also, as a heads up: If you use flexbox, you will need vendor prefixes for those styles for safari and IE 11. There are a lot of online tools that will do it for you like this: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: @user1607991 paste your updated code and we can help you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` to the `:after` element - pseudo elements require this for block layout.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but it still doesn't allow me to put the line underneath the element?

Comment: you're using `position: absolute;` which will position the element absolutely.. why are you using that? Tbh I'd follow the answer above mine, it's more comprehensive (although rather than ask him to explain Flexbox you should probably Google it and do some reading first).

Comment: Right on... Thanks! I used absolute because I was trying to stack it.

Comment: The default behaviour is stacking.. `position: absolute;` is for when you want to force a certain behaviour.